# Cordova FCM on Android

Tags: android, firebase, cordova, ionic-framework

I have this error, any one help me to fix this issue ?

`Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.`

> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (*information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/*) or updating the version of `com.google.android.gms` to 10+.

```
   dependencies {
      implementation fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
      // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
        implementation(project(path: ":CordovaLib"))
        compile "com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+"
        compile "com.soundcloud.android:android-crop:1.0.0@aar"
        compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1"
        compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1"
        compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.+"
        compile "com.android.support:support-annotations:27.+"
        compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23+"
        compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10+"
        compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10+"
        // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For SDK versions 15 and lower, all Firebase and Play Services SDKs must be the same version. So:

```
dependencies {
  implementation fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
  // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
    implementation(project(path: ":CordovaLib"))
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+"
    compile "com.soundcloud.android:android-crop:1.0.0@aar"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1"
    compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.+"
    compile "com.android.support:support-annotations:27.+"
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23+"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.1"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.1"
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
}
```